# What is a Post Stamp

Tags: phrase-request

What is a post stamp? For example: this?
[image: pic]
If so, what is the stamp the post office stamps onto the letter, which contains the address and the date?
What's this called: [image: pic]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the US, the first one is a *postage stamp*, and the second is a *postmark*.

The term "post stamp" isn't commonly used here.

Comment: I'd say same for the UK.

Comment: To clarify on that last comment, _post stamp_ isn't used very often; you're more likely to hear _postage stamp_, or, if the context makes it obvious, just _stamp_. When I'm at the post office, for example, I can simply tell the clerk, "I need 10 stamps, please." The clerk will know I mean _postage_ stamps.

Comment: @J.R. By "not commonly used" I mean it's not a set phrase with any specific meaning, but it isn't grammatically wrong. For example, we might use the phrase "post stamp" to mean a stamp placed on a soccer goal post to show it's had an annual safety inspection, or a stamp placed on a document to show it's been read by the occupants of a guard post.

Comment: @Photon - Thanks for clarifying. I just thought the English learner might be left wanting more information after reading that last sentence.